# What is a good way to seal LP Smartsheet siding?

Tags: siding, shed

So rather a self-explanatory issue.

The building walls are at a height that isn’t conducive to use a full sheet of 4x8 LP smart sheet (series 38) so I have to cut it down, but the offcuts are a good amount so I didn’t want to waste it, especially since this is DIY and budget is everything.

Anyway, if I say use the offcuts to create a full sheet (once it’s on the wall) what can be done about the horizontal seam that isn’t in any sort of stud? It just feels wrong, but it’ll be a real bummer to waste such pieces. Hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Can always add extra studs or blocking(horizontal pieces between studs) if needed for a mounting surface.

Comment: Is this the _only_ exterior covering going over the studs, or is there plywood/OSB over the studs then this _siding_ covering the sheathing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go stronger than @crip659.

If you want to use all the off-cuts, you should install horizontal pieces between studs (called dwangs in New Zealand).  You need to support the joins otherwise they will separate when someone leans, pushes, or falls against them.